# Plotting constraints in 3D

Tags: 3d, plot, constraints, inequalities

I would like to be able to visualise a volume (or the surface representing its bound) defined by constraints in 3D.
More precisely, I have some constraints, for example

```
f0(x,y,z)=(( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((-20.0/1.0) * (y)) + ((-380.0/1.0) * (x)))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((-380.0/1.0) * (y)) + ((-20.0/1.0) * (x)))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((-380.0/1.0) * (x)) + ((-20.0/1.0) * (y)))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((-20.0/1.0) * (z)) + ((-380.0/1.0) * (y)))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((380.0/1.0) * (y)) + ((20.0/1.0) * (x)))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((380.0/1.0) * (x)) + ((20.0/1.0) * (z)))) ) &&
          ( not ((628.0/1.0) < (((-1520.0/1.0) * (y)) + ((-80.0/1.0) * (z)))) ) &&
          ( not ((2983.0/1.0) < (((380.0/1.0) * (y)) + ((7220.0/1.0) * (z)))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((-20.0/1.0) * (x)) + ((-380.0/1.0) * (z)))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((20.0/1.0) * (z)) + ((380.0/1.0) * (x)))) ) &&
          ( not ((9.0/1.00) < (((1.0/1.0) * (z)) + (((1.0/1.0) * (x)) + ((1.0/1.0) * (y))))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((20.0/1.0) * (z)) + ((380.0/1.0) * (y)))) ) &&
          ( not ((7845120.0/1.0) < (((-8716800.0/1.0) * (x)) + (((-8716800.0/1.0) * (z)) + ((-8716800.0/1.0) * (y))))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((-380.0/1.0) * (z)) + ((-20.0/1.0) * (y)))) ) &&
          ( not ((629.0/1.0) < (((80.0/1.0) * (x)) + ((1520.0/1.0) * (y)))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((20.0/1.0) * (x)) + ((380.0/1.0) * (y)))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((380.0/1.0) * (x)) + ((20.0/1.0) * (y)))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((-380.0/1.0) * (z)) + ((-20.0/1.0) * (x)))) ) &&
          ( not ((629.0/1.0) < (((-1520.0/1.0) * (y)) + ((-80.0/1.0) * (x)))) ) &&
          ( not ((629.0/1.0) < (((-80.0/1.0) * (y)) + ((-1520.0/1.0) * (z)))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((-380.0/1.0) * (y)) + ((-20.0/1.0) * (z)))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((-20.0/1.0) * (z)) + ((-380.0/1.0) * (x)))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((20.0/1.0) * (x)) + ((380.0/1.0) * (z)))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((-20.0/1.0) * (x)) + ((-380.0/1.0) * (y)))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((380.0/1.0) * (y)) + ((20.0/1.0) * (z)))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((-20.0/1.0) * (y)) + ((-380.0/1.0) * (z)))) ) &&
          ( not ((629.0/1.0) < (((-80.0/1.0) * (x)) + ((-1520.0/1.0) * (z)))) ) &&
          ( not ((157.0/1.0) < (((-380.0/1.0) * (x)) + ((-20.0/1.0) * (z)))) ) &&
          ( not ((2983.0/1.0) < (((380.0/1.0) * (z)) + ((7220.0/1.0) * (x)))) ))
```

and I want to see the subspace it represents.

I tried various tools for that (gnuplot, matlab) but could not find any way to do what I want to do.

Comment: If you're prepared to code something, this could be done in OpenGL

Comment: This feature is needed in a big framework in which bringing OpenGL is out of the question. I was looking for a simple way to do it but I guess I'll just have to accept it will stay as text...
Thank you for your answer though.